# bourne shell expr inside if-statements

Tags: sh

Can I use the expr command inside if-statements? I am seeing very strange behaviour of the following small script:

```
if (`expr $1 > $2`)
then
    echo $1
else
    echo $2
fi
```

It works as intended for > and <, but gives a syntax error or "Command not found" for =, or <=, >= and pretty much everything else.

Am I doing something wrong?

I know I can use [ ] or test instead.

Comment: By work, you probably mean there is no syntax error. The operators are being treated as redirection by the shell, not comparison operators passed to `expr`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you don't have to use command substitution. You can just redirect the output to `/dev/null` and check the exit code. You should also quote special characters like redirection characters.

```
if expr "$1" '>' "$2" >/dev/null
then
    echo "$1"
else
    echo "$2"
fi
```